# Separate the string in Python, excluding some elements which contain separator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a really ugly string like this:

```
# ugly string follows:
ugly_string1 = SVEF/XX:1/60/24.02.16 07:30:00/"isk/kWh"/0/ENDTIME
# which also may look like this (part within quotes is different):
ugly_string2 = SVEF/XX:1/60/24.02.16 07:30:00/"kWh"/0/ENDTIME
```

and I'd like to separate it to get this list in Python:

```
['SVEF/XX:1', '60', '24.02.16 07:30:00', '"isk/kWh"', '0', 'ENDTIME']
# or from the second string:
['SVEF/XX:1', '60', '24.02.16 07:30:00', '"kWh"', '0', 'ENDTIME']
```

The first element (`SVEF/XX:1`) will **always** be the same, but the fourth element might or might not have the separator character in it (`/`).

I came up with regex which isolates the 1st and the 4th element ([example here](https://regex101.com/r/aR7uE8/1)):

```
(?=(SVEF/XX:1))|(?=("(.*?)"))
```

but I just cannot figure out how to separate the rest of the string by `/` character, while excluding those two isolated elements?

I can do it with more "manual" approach, with regex like this ([example here](https://regex101.com/r/xM0lF2/1)):

```
([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/("[^"]+")/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

but when I try this out in Python, I get extra empty elements for some reason:

```
['', 'SVEF/XX:1', '60', '24.02.16 07:30:00', '"isk/kWh"', '0', 'ENDTIME', '']
```

I could sanitize this result afterwards, but it would be great if I separate those strings without extra interventions.

Comment: [`^([^:]+:\d+)\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+)\/(".*?")\/(\d+)\/(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/tR2nW5/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, they are all good and very helpful! However, after trying to test the performance of each one I came up with surprising results. You can take a look [here](http://ideone.com/I9rS3t),
but essentially, `timit` module ended up every time with results similar to this:

```
============================================================
example from my question:
0.21345195919275284
============================================================
Tushar's comment on my question:
0.21896087005734444
============================================================
alexis' answer (although not completely correct answer):
0.2645496800541878
============================================================
Casimir et Hippolyte's answer:
0.3663317859172821
============================================================
Simon Fraser's csv answer:
1.398559506982565
```

So, I decided to stick with my own example:

```
([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/("[^"]+")/([^/]+)/([^/]+)`)
```

but I'll reward your efforts nevertheless!

Comment: You've chosen a solution on the basis of execution speed? How many of these records are you going to be splitting? (Hint: If your runtime is longer than it took you to write this question and self-answer, you're on the right track...)

Comment: Well, I am processing files, each with near 100k rows... More than half of lines are formatted like this and files are collected twice a day. If you think performance here is irrelevant, feel free to prove it to me... My answer came a bit late because this particular thing wasn't on the top of my priority list and also person has to take a weekend break from time to time ;)

Comment: D'accord. You didn't mention performance in the question, and usually this kind of thing would be used only once on a file of a few thousand lines-- if that. (PS don't worry, I didn't think you spent all weekend on this question! A half-hour would be more than most scripts will ever burn.)

Comment: Yeah, true, I didn't mention performance because I really didn't think that regex string only could affect it so drastically in the first place... Every day you learn something new :) The line we are talking about is indeed sort of a  "header" row, but in example files which I got and which I should process, it is repeating very often... Better be prepared for the worst! :)

Answer (score 4):

In python, this can be done more easily (and with more room to generalize or adapt the approach in the future) with successive uses of `split()` and `rsplit()`.

```
ugly_string = 'SVEF/XX:1/60/24.02.16 07:30:00/"isk/kWh"/0/ENDTIME'
temp = ugly_string.split("/", maxsplit=4)
result = [ temp[0]+"/"+temp[1] ] + temp[2:-1] + temp[-1].rsplit("/", maxsplit=2)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
['SVEF/XX:1', '60', '24.02.16 07:30:00', '"isk/kWh"', '0', 'ENDTIME']
```

I use the second argument of `split/rsplit` to limit how many slashes are split; 
I first split as many parts off the left as possible (i.e., 4), and rejoin parts 0 and 1 
(the `SVEF` and `XX`). I then use `rsplit()` to make the rest of the split from the right. What's left in the middle is the quoted word, regardless of what it contains.

Rejoining the first two parts isn't too elegant, but neither is a format that allows `/` to appear both as a field separator and inside an unquoted field.

Comment: I'll stop typing my answer now that you've given the exact same solution. The only difference I'd have made is to explicitly name the `maxsplit` argument, which I believe improves readability.

Comment: Maybe it does, you're right. It certainly helps explain the code, so I've adopted your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: My initial idea was similar to this, but the regex approach looks more "elegant" to me personally (at least comparing the amount of code). You also have an error in your example - I don't have to separate the date and time.

Comment: Oops, sorry @errata! I didn't notice that date and time are a single field. Fixed now, and simpler. It's a matter of taste which approach you prefer, I suppose. But I'd rather look at the amount of time it takes to read (and understand/debug), not at the "amount of code". (Otherwise we should all be programming in perl, not python :-)).

Comment: @alexis No worries at all! I appreciate the effort! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall` testing first the quoted parts and making the beginning optional in the second branch:

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|/)("[^"]*"|(?:^[^/]*/)?[^/"]*)', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's csv module can handle multiple different delimiters, if you're ok with reinserting the `"` in the field where it seems to always exist, and reassembling the first field.

If you have a string, and want to treat it as a csv file, you can do this to prepare:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> ugly_string1 = 'SVEF/XX:1/60/24.02.16 07:30:00/"isk/kWh"/0/ENDTIME'
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(ugly_string1)
```

Otherwise, assuming `f` is an open file, or the object we just created above:

```
>>> reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='/')
>>> for row in reader:
>>>    print(row)
['SVEF', 'XX:1', '60', '24.02.16 07:30:00', 'isk/kWh', '0', 'ENDTIME']
>>> first = "/".join(row[0:2])
```

Comment: +1, I thought too that the format is a bit CSV-like (though the first "field" is completely ad hoc). But to make this into an answer, you need to show how it would take input from a variable, not a file. (Hint: `StringIO` is your friend).

Comment: I left out StringIO because I'd assumed (perhaps falsely) that the OP was reading from a file. I can add it, though

Comment: And you may well be right! Since the goal is not to please _me_, you can explain and show both scenarios. (I'd also fix the OP's syntax error on line 3 :-))

Comment: Good spot! Fixed now